# iOS: NSPredicate Issue with Magical Record?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nspredicate, magicalrecord

My app downloads objects from a server, and adds each item into Core Data using Magical Record. Rather than delete every object and re-download everything every time, I want to only download new items (I've figured this part out), and check if objects on the server (parse) have been deleted, and thus delete them locally to sync it up (This is what I'm having trouble doing).

What I'm trying to do is fetch all the objects stored in Core Data, and using an NSPredicate filter, get an array of items that exist in this local array from Core Data, but not in the objects retrieved (This would indicate that they've been deleted on the server... I'm using Parse), and so I'd like to delete them.

This is what I'm doing:

```
//Fetch local objects from core data (objects is an array returned by the server)
NSPredicate *deletedObjectsOnServer = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (objectId IN %@)", objects];
NSArray *localObjectsArray = [MyObject MR_findAllWithPredicate:deletedObjectsOnServer];

NSLog(@"Deleted Files on server: %@", localObjectsArray);
```

The problem is I'm getting the following error:

```
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (objectId IN     
{<MyObject:0x156e8210, objectId: WXwBOQ73KS, localId: (null)>*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `objects` array contains an instance of `MyObject`, while in the predicate you want to filter by `objectId` property which is (probably) a `NSString`.

Changing the array passed to the `NSPredicate` to contain `objectId` values should do the trick:

```
NSPredicate *deletedObjectsOnServer = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (objectId IN %@)", [objects valueForKey:@"objectId"]];
```